# T-SQL column that indicates one or more records exist in a separate table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a query that selects **all** records from **tableA** and no other records. However, I want my query to include a column that indicates that 1 or more records exist in **tableB**.

LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA to tableB doesn't work because if there are 2 records in tableB that relate to a record in tableA I get 2 records in the result set. I only want 1.

RIGHT OUTER JOIN doesn't work because my query returns all of the records in tableB that do not match to any records in tableA. I do not want to get records from tableB that do not match at least 1 record in tableA.

INNER JOIN also fails because I do not get **all** of the records in tableA; only those that contain a matching record in tableB.

It's as if I need a query like this:

```
SELECT tableA.ID, IF EXISTS row in tableB THEN 1 ELSE 0 
FROM tableA <some sort of join> tableB on tableA.ID = tableB.FKtoTableA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that the goal is to merely test for existence then we highly suggest using the [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) clause in-line:

```
SELECT A.*
     , CASE
           WHEN EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
               FROM TableB B
               WHERE B.Id = A.Id
           ) THEN 1
           ELSE 0 
       END 
FROM TableA A
```

Not only is this [typically going to be faster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46359/check-existence-with-exists-outperform-count-not) than a solution that employs a `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NOT NULL` or a `COUNT` and has the added benefit of having semantics that agree with your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery:

select 
tableA.*,
(select count(*) from tableB where tableA.ID=tableB.ID) as 'Count in TableB'
from tableA

You could wrap a conditional or case statement around the subquery to give you a more Boolean value if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `left join` and only pull in aggregate data from b:

```
select a.id, cast(count(b.id) as bit) from a left join b on a.id = b.id group by a.id;
```

[example](http://rextester.com/IRNPR83716)

Converting to `bit` promotes any nonzero value to 1.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but instead of counting rows, you could just use isnulll(select top 1 1 ... ,0)